# Identify the subset of the plane composed by $R\cos \theta=5$ by means of polar coordinates $R,\theta$?

Tags: geometry

I did the following on Mathematica:

I assumed values for $R$ in the pair $(R,\theta)$ [with $R\neq 0$] and then used `Solve[]` to find the value for $\cos \theta$ such that the equation $R\cos \theta=5$ holds. Then I plotted it, the commands I used on Mathematica are the following:

`A = Table[{R, Solve[R x == 5, x][[1]][[1]][[2]]}, {R, 0.001, 5, .1}];
B = Table[{R, Solve[R x == 5, x][[1]][[1]][[2]]}, {R, -5, -.001, .1}];
Union[A, B] // ListLinePlot`

I believe the subset of the plane is the following plot:

> [image]

Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The polar coordinates are expressed as $(R,\theta)$ and these points are located in the cartesian plane with the coordinates $(R \sin \theta, R \cos \theta)$. And then, having:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  {R\cos\theta}&=&{5} \\ 
  {R}&=&{\frac{5}{\cos\theta}}
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Then making the appropriate substitutions:

$$\left( \frac{5}{\cos\theta},\theta\right)\rightarrow \left(\frac{5 \cos \theta}{\cos \theta},\frac{5 \sin \theta}{\cos \theta} \right)=\left(5,\frac{5\sin \theta}{\cos\theta} \right)$$

Then the graph is the set of points $\left[\left(5,\frac{5\sin \theta}{\cos\theta} \right):\theta\in\mathbb{R} \right]$ and the graph is:

> $\quad\quad$[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use Mathematica to see the polar equation $\,r\cos\theta=5\,$ defines the straight line $\,x=5\,$ in cartesian coordinates! Or did I miss something?

Comment: I don't know, I'm a bit confused with the book instructions. It says that the polar coordinates are $(R, \theta)$ and the cartesian coordinates of this point are $(R \cos \theta, R \sin \theta)$. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @Vÿska  Remember that $$\cos\theta = \frac{x}{r}$$  Thus, $r\cos\theta = x$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I figured it now! Thanks.